# Need suggestion regarding wsdl element changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, wsdl

I have created a webservice with a function

```
[WebMethod]
public void Case(Case case)
{
}
```

I need to expose my web service to another team which says that I need to make some changes.
When he pointed that my wsdl looks like this:

```
<s:element name="Case">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
name="case" type="s1:Case" />
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

And he wants to see the wsdl as:

```
<s:element name="Case">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Message" type="util:Message" />
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CaseHeader" type="util:CaseHeader" />
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

the two elements are the internals classes for the Case.

Comment: Not really sure what the question is.

Comment: Actually I want to make the wsdl like the second one

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to play with DataContract serialization attributes to modify how your data objects are serialized.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. Has this other team given you a WSDL and told you to go implement a web service that conforms to that WSDL?

Because otherwise, you've got it backwards. If you get to define the web service, then they get to consume the resulting WSDL. The "other team" usually doesn't get to say what the WSDL looks like, unless they provided it to you.